# Target closest icon to change it into another icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of cards in the same page. Below is the example the example below where I have put for this example only 1 card (but there are many more).

I fail to use jquery 'closest' or 'siblings' or something similar to do the following: when a user click on a card it collapses and the javascript kicks in to show the content. I need at that moment to replace the "plus icon" by a "minus icon". (only on this specific card so not using at any point a id or class containing the number of the card '354' in the example below)

[Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hn6ntbmy/11/)

The Javascript should target the icon but it does not change it when I click

If you have trouble making appear the content, do not worry, it's not the focus of the question. I just want to know how to target the icon and change into to glyphicon minus.

HTML

```
   <div id="operation-zone">
    <ul class="cards-list">

    <li class="card 354" data-opcode="CATIMINI26">

        <div class="card-content" id="accordion_354"> 

      <a class="card-detail-opener" id="BtnHomeOperationExpand_53313" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_354" href="#collapseOne_354" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne_354">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus detail-icon_354"></i>
      </a>

      <div class="card-image card-lazy-preloader" id="accordion2">              
        <a href="/campaigns/xxxxx">
                    </a><figure><a href="/campaigns/xxxxxx">            
                        <!-- responsive image -->
                        <img style="opacity: 1; display: block;" id="HPImageBanner_354" src="http://vp-eu.scene7.com/is/image/vpeu/0/00_54093_FR_brandvisualnbrandvisualfr">  
                    </figure>

            </div>



        </div> 

      <div id="collapseOne_354" class="smux details details_354 panel-collapse collapse left-aligned" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="height: auto;">
          <div id="DivHomeOperationDates" class="dates">
              Jusqu'au <span class="brand-color">mercredi 06/04 6h</span>
          </div>

          <div id="DivHomeOperationDescription_52850" class="description">
              operation in venicesqqsqssqsqsqsqsqsqss qui ravira les petits et les grands ! Retrouvez Les Schtroumpfs, Les Rebelles de la Foret, Hotel Transylvanie et bien d'autres encore... 
          </div>

          <div class="card-info-actions">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="/campaigns/operation-in-venicesqqsqssqsqsqsqsqsqss">go Now &gt;</a>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!-- end of campaign card details on 1-column view-->


    </li>

            </ul>


    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#collapseOne_354').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
});
$('#collapseOne_354').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
```

CSS

```
.cards-list {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
.card {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;     
    position: relative;
}

.card-content {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.card-image {
    vertical-align: top;
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      color: green; 
    }
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 33.88%;
}
.container .jumbotron {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.card-detail-opener {  
        color: green;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 1px;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      line-height: 27px;
      background: grey;
        position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      opacity: .75;
      filter: alpha(opacity=75);
      bottom: 60%;
      right: 30%;
        &:hover { background: #7E7E7E; }
        &:focus { background: #7E7E7E; }
    }

}

.card-detail-opener:link {
    color: green;

}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove {
    color: #333;
    &:hover { color: green; }
    &:focus {   color: green; }
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus { 
     top:1px;
        color: #333;
        &:hover { color: #ffffff; }
        &:focus {   color: #ffffff; }

}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-minus {    
        top:2px;
        padding-right: 2px;//tweak to center
        color: #333;
        &:hover { color: #ffffff; }
        &:focus {   color: #ffffff; }

}


// Content of the card details in the 1-column view
.card .details {

        padding-top: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);

}
.details {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
.details .dates { 
    padding-top: 10px; 
    font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  color: #464650;
  margin-right: 1em;
  background-size: 90px auto !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position-x: right !important;
  background-position-y: 0px !important;    
  margin-bottom: 8px; 
}
.details .baseline {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    line-height: 0.4em;
}
.details .description {
    font-size: .65em;
    color: #464650; 
    line-height: 1.1em;
    overflow: hidden;

}
// End of content of the card details in the 1-column view
.card-info-actions {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 5px 2px 0;
    clear: both;
}
//smaller buttons for cards
.card-info-actions .btn-primary {
    font-size: 15px;
}

.card-short-info a.dateSales {
  color: #464650;
}
.info-overlay {
  display:none;
  z-index:999;
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCFFFFFF,endColorstr=#CCFFFFFF)\9";
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCFFFFFF,endColorstr=#CCFFFFFF);
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 4px solid green;
}

.close-overlay {
  float:right;
  padding:5px;
}

.info-overlay a {
    display: block;
    line-height: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: "If you have trouble making appear the content, do not worry, it's not the focus of the question." ...but you bind to the `shown.bs.collapse` and `hidden.bs.collapse` events of the `collapse` widget. These events won't fire if the show/hide mechanism isn't working.

Comment: I know. I'm really sorry, on my local app it's working. I tried to put the necessary code on jsfiddle but I don't know why the content is not appearing when you click on the 'plus' icon. To be faire, here I just need to know how to target the 'plus' icon to change it into the minus icon. On my app the $('#collapseOne').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () and $('#collapseOne').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () are working

Comment: Ah, I see. No worries. For the future, JSFiddle requires all libraries to be included in order in the external dependencies list. The problem was that Bootstrap JS was included before JQuery. The easiest way to include JQuery so that other libraries can use it correctly is to click on the `JavaScript {Gear Image}` in the editor area and choose a JQuery version from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is wrong `collapseOne_354` while you are binding `collapseOne`

EDIT
I would reach the glyphicon with

```
var list = $('.cards-list')
$('li', list).click(function(e){ 
  var card=$(this);
  $(this).find(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-minus").toggleClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
```

Comment: the jsfiddle is right. i know. I don't want to actually use any id or class with a variable number (here 354) but target with jquery the closest card.

Comment: I cant' use the ID collpaseONe as , as explained, I will in reality have a whole page full of 100 cards each having a different id (collpaseOne_1, collpaseOne_45, collpaseOne_376, ...) . So I need to use closest(), sibling() or something similar to change the 'plus' icon  ONLY for the card that has been clicked, not the others. The jsfiddle is not 100% working for some unknow reasons but my question remains: how to properly target via jquery

Comment: it's working. super great. I'm a newbie so I don't even understand how you could target only one card without using closest() or parent(). But it's working. You're not even listening to the events such as on('shown.bs.collapse')

Comment: This code `var list = $('.cards-list'); $('li', list).click(...)` does the magic of bind the click event of *every li child of list*